# Is there a straightforward way to combine successive string values representing 15-minute blocks of time?

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, time, string-formatting

Currently, I'm returning feedback to the user in this form:

```
"<UserName> removed 07:00, 07:15, 07:30, 07:45, 08:00, 08:15, 08:30, 09:00, 09:15, 09:30, 09:45, 10:00, 10:15, 10:30, 11:15, (etc.)"
```

...Understandably, they want it to be more user-friendly, such as this instead:

```
<UserName> removed 07:00 - 8:30, 9:00 - 10:30, 11:15 - (etc.)
```

Rather than rework the whole method that concatenates these values into a StringBuilder, I'd like to take that first output and morph it into the second; something like:

```
sbQuarterHoursRemoved = CombineSucceedingQuarterHours(sbQuarterHoursRemoved);
```

Is this as tedious as it appears to me, or does somebody know a relatively painless way of accomplishing it?

### UPDATE

I adapted the code below to this:

```
String QuarterHoursRemovedPrettified = PrettifyQuarterHoursRemoved(sbQuarterHoursRemoved);
. . .

private static string PrettifyQuarterHoursRemoved(StringBuilder sbQuarterHoursRemoved)
{
    string[] times = sbQuarterHoursRemoved.ToString().Split(',');
    DateTime prevDt = new DateTime(1);
    string prevString = "";

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string time in times) {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        if (dt.Subtract(prevDt).TotalMinutes > 15) {
            if (prevString != "")
                output.Append(" " + prevString + ",");
            output.Append(" " + time + " -");
        }
        prevString = time;
        prevDt = dt;
    }
    output.Remove(output.Length - 1, 1);
    return output.ToString(); 
}
```

With values in times like this (after the call to Split()):

```
00:45
01:00
01:15
22:45
23:00
```

It ALWAYS crashes the second pass through the loop. The first goes fine, but the second time, no matter what value, crashes.
e.g., the first time through, dt becomes:

```
dt = 6/26/2012 12:45 am
```

...after the call to ParseExact()

...but the second call to ParseExact() - with, for example, "01:00" as the value in "time" fails.

Some error details are:

*System.FormatException was unhandled
  Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
       at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider)
       at TitanNextGen_Platypi.PlatypiMainForm.PrettifyQuarterHoursRemoved(StringBuilder sbQuarterHoursRemoved) in...*

### UPDATED AGAIN

It works now - untrimmed vals were the problem. When the value was, for example, " 01:15" instead of "01:15" all Dallas broke loose (and I changed "hh:mm" to "HH:mm" in the call to ParseExact() to account for 24-hour time)

Comment: So ...what's wrong with `StringBuilder.AppendFormat(...)`??? Other than you don't *want* to use it? It really is the easiest way.

Comment: How are you building that string?

Comment: @IAbstract: You're assuming I knew about .AppendFormat(); and that I didn't want to use it.

Comment: The easiest place to do it is in the method that concatenates the string now. That's where you're iterating over the times. To do it after the fact, you have deconstruct the string and basically do that all over again anyway.

Comment: @John: I'm looping through the faux cells in a LayoutPanel, and for each one that has a value in it, appending the appropriate value ("08:30" or "08:45" or "13:15" etc.) to a StringBuilder, followed by a comma. Only when I've finished writing to the StringBuilder do I know what "stretches" of time are represented.

Comment: @hatchet: But as the SB is being constructed, I don't know (at the time) when I've come to the end of the successive array of contiguous 15-minute intervals; I only know that when I add a value that is > 15 minutes in the future from the previous one.

Comment: @ClayShannon: fair enough ...I did *assume* that since you mentioned `StringBuilder` you were familiar with the class methods. :)

Comment: @ClayShannon - make two temp strings or DateTimes called rangeStart and rangeEnd. When you start a new range, set rangeStart and rangeEnd to that start time. As you hit subsequent times that should be in the same range, keep updating rangeEnd with those new times. When you hit the first time outside that range, add the string for the range you just built to SB, and start building a new range with that new out of range time. Remember to add the final range when done looping.

Comment: @IAbstract: Isn't that like assuming if a person knows who Marlon Brando is, he knows about the movie "Morituri"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are processing the strings, you will need to keep track of where you are at and if you need to start a new sequence:

```
    string[] times = { "07:00", "07:15", "07:30", "07:45", "08:00", "08:15", "08:30", "09:00", "09:15", "09:30", "09:45", "10:00", "10:15", "10:30", "11:15" };

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime prevDt = new DateTime(1);
        string prevString = "";

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("UserXyz Deleted ");
        foreach (string time in times)
        {

            DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(time,"hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            if (dt.Subtract(prevDt).TotalMinutes > 15)
            {
                if (prevString != "")
                    output.Append(" " + prevString + ",");
                output.Append(" " + time + " -");
            }
            prevString = time;
            prevDt = dt;
        }
        output.Remove(output.Length - 1, 1);
        MessageBox.Show(output.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you will need to write your own function, because you are manipulating a string, and not raw data. That said, you will be able to do it in linear time (you will only have to parse the string once).

Steps include:

1. Tokenize the string (using commas as the delimiters)
2. Loop through these tokens, incrementing your response variables for each successive 15 minute interval.

   ```
   7:00, 7:15, 7:30, 7:45, 8:30
   7:00 - 7:30, 7:45, 8:30
   7:00 - 7:45, 8:30
   ```

Just a general overview of the process. You'll need to look into a string tokenizer (i'm a java guy, myself, but I know there is one built in) You *should* be able to index into the tokens to reference the hours and the tens of minutes digits and use a switch statement to respond accordingly.